# What could you call a library of medical images and other data relating to bones or skeletons?

Tags: single-word-requests, software

I'm looking for a concise term for a library or collection including medical images of bones. More precisely it contains multimodal (e.g. X-ray and CT-scan) medical images of subsections of a skeleton (e.g. around the hip or around the knee) along with lots of other contextual and derived information.

- The term doesn't need to cover the complete definition above so something that implies 'a collection of bones' would be adequate in the context it would be used.
- The data is used to develop planning software for joint-replacement operations.
- It's not a 'marketing' term directly but might get used in academic contexts and in discussions with surgeons.
- Established terms like 'ossuary' would all come with strong associations and don't seem quite right. Most of the people the data relates to are very much alive.

Comment: Boneyard? . . .

Comment: I've retagged this because we don't provide neologisms. That tag is for asking about neologisms you've encountered already. We do have [help for single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info): please review that to make sure the checklist at the bottom has been covered (most if not all has).

Comment: **Osteology** is the study of bones and an **osteological collection** is a [collection of bone specimens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoological_specimen#Skeletal_Preparations_(Osteology)), a subtype of an anatomical collection. Doesn't really match the requirements for a snappy single-word name though. I don't think you're going to get a term involving bones that isn't morbid (either relating to death or disease). The phrase "bone library" is also used (at least in literature and metaphorical senses) but I'm not sure of its origin.

Comment: So there's a physical collection (scattered? centralized?) of bones that have been removed from people who have had bone transplants, and you have a dataset that catalogs those removed bones?  And there is also a collection of related radiological scans?   And you want a name for the combined catalog?

Comment: And you want a descriptive name, not a marketing name?

Comment: You have described a collection of pictures, not a collection of bones. It'd be kind of silly to claim I had a collection of rare gemstones, when it's just a photo album of emeralds and rubies.

Comment: An ossuary is a **physical collection of bones**. Is that what **you mean**,  really? CT scans and X-rays provide a "record of patients' bone issues". Isn't that the idea??

Comment: You should ask this in chat, there is a person who participates there who knows this stuff very well.

Comment: What you describe is not a ‘collection of bones’, it’s a collection of _medical images of bones_. There is a _huge_ difference in meaning there, and I suspect part of your issue finding an acceptable term stems from that difference (for the record, an ossuary is the first thing I thought of reading the question title, but it also doesn’t describe what you are talking about at all).

Comment: Can you say to whom terms like 'ossuary' come with strong associations and if so, why that's a problem?

To find something 'a bit less... dead…' why not ask all your colleagues what word they might use, given a choice from any language?

What would be wrong with something based on anatomy, physiology or some sort of therapy?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I've edited to try and clarify the question. In the context the word would tend to be used it would be obvious that it wasn't literally a collection of bones. In future the dataset could include identifiers that link to a physical specimen but that isn't the case at the moment.

Comment: If there is a requirement to retain these images, then I think *repository* is a good choice. But if the collection is curated with an eye towards retrieval for commercial or educational purposes, I'd just use *library.*

Comment: Sounds like **Pfizer skeletal image corpus** or  **Pfizer bone and joint digital corpus**

Comment: A dataset. Not really specific to your case, but it's usually called a dataset in fields where it is a common thing to have (Machine learning/Computer science).

Answer (score 16):

Do the former patients have easy access to this data? I wouldn't think so. Would there be requests to see old PET scans, MRI images by former patients? Perhaps, but I doubt the images would come with a morbid reminder of their mortality.

On the other hand, experts such as surgeons, physicians, oncologists etc. would not flinch or feel awkward if they read the term "ossuary", but they would feel puzzled as the word means a container or a room of *dead people's* bones.

I'd suggest **[imaging repository](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36670459/)**, obviously the term would not be exclusive to images of bones; if scans, MRIs and Xrays of bones  are an essential component then the Greek prefix **osteo–** could be used: ***osteography*** **repository** might fit. [Osteography](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/osteography) is a rare word but it is listed in Merriam-Webster's dictionary.

> :descriptive *osteology*

Comment: For a brand-like name, these suggestions provide a source of inspiration (noting that there's already an ["OsteoBase"](https://osteobase.mnhn.fr/) which seems to be about the bone structures of fish)

Comment: Yes, _osteography_ is the pertinent term here.  A slight variant on this: **osteographic library** (or archive) might be suitable.  Extending a bit leads to creations such as "osteopædia".

Comment: @TobySpeight I would suggest **Œstonicon**, by analogy with "lexicon" and "onomasticon".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's a skeletal corpus.

You could say "skeletal image corpus" - but why? What else would it be?

Note that these days you don't have to call things a "database" anymore - what else could it be?

It would likely just be called "bone images" or " bone images" or perhaps " bone image collection".